# Как правильно согласовать словосочетание?

Tags: семантика

1.Настроение и мысль, которую они передают.(слова)
2.Настроение и мысль, которые они передают.(слова)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Настроение и мысль, которые они передают(слова).***

Придаточное определительное относится к обоим существительным, поэтому согласование делается **во мн. числе.**

Здесь можно применить **правило Розенталя о постпозитивном определении, относящемся к двум однородным членам:**

Определение ставится в форме множественного числа:

2)      если определение постпозитивно, например: Мелкие повреждения кожи смазываются настойкой йода или бриллиантовой зеленью, **предохраняющими** от гнойничковых заболеваний.

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_05](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_05)